# How do I make a slow "for loop" faster with multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading, for-loop

Let's say I have a very slow and big for loop.

How do I split this up in multiple threads so it runs faster?

```
for (int a = 0; a < 30_000_000; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 30_000_000; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 30_000_000; c++) {
           slowMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no general answer to this question.  `slowMethod()` has to be designed correctly so that it can exploit parallelism or you won't see a speed up.

Comment: The loop structure itself isnt slow. And since you do not use `a, b, c`, you could as well have a single loop from `0` to `Math.pow(30_000_000, 3)`. The slow part is `slowMethod` and the fact that it runs sequentially, blocking. You just have to make sure to post it in its own thread, for example by using an `ExecutorService`. Obviously the method has to be designed in a thread-safe way for that to work. There might also be much better approaches, like a fork&join maybe, but that depends on what exactly the method is doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a little bit broad, but use an `ExecutorService` with fixed thread number will make it faster when the processor number is greater than 1 and the `slowMethod` is independent. If the `slowMethod` is I/O intensive, you can increase the thread number to get higer performance.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                   Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() + 1);

        for (int a = 0; a < 30000000; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 30000000; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < 30000000; c++) {
                    final int a_copy = a;
                    final int b_copy = b;
                    final int c_copy = c;
                    service.execute(() -> {
                            slowMethod(a_copy, b_copy, c_copy);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void slowMethod(int a, int b, int c) {

    }
}
```

---

Update

As said in the comment, it might cause task abortion since the queue's capacity is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. You can let the main thread execute `slowMethod` when the queue is full. To achieve this, you need create the pool mannually:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threads, threads,
        0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        queue, Executors.defaultThreadFactory(),
        new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Great answer

Comment: That uses an unbounded queue. Adding 3e7 * 3e7 * 3e7 = 2.7e28 entries to a queue is not a good idea (overflow).